# phpmailer not handling Iphone subject line in emails

Tags: iphone, outlook, phpmailer

I am using the following script to email our website users:

```
function mailerExpressBlueHost(array $mailInputs){   

    require_once '../../includes/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';  

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsMail();   
    $mail->SetFrom('swag@sustainablewestonma.org');
    $mail->addAddress($mailInputs['addAddress']);   // use for production;
    $mail->AddBCC("swag@sustainablewestonma.org"); // set BCC: counts as part of the 500 limit;        
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage("../images/newswagimageSmall.jpg", "swag-logo");    
    $mail->Subject = $mailInputs['subject'] ;
    $mail->Body    = $mailInputs['body'];
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->ContentType="text/HTML";    

    if(!$mail->send()) {             
        $msg = 'Message could not be sent.' . 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }else{
        $msg = 'Message has been sent';
    }

    $mail->ClearAddresses(); 
    return $msg;   

}
```

when viewing the email in ms outlook the email looks like:

[image: email in outlook]

but when viewed on an Iphone it looks like:

[image: email on iphone]

Is there a way to either hide or place in the header the subject line instead of it appearing in the body? (the subject line being: SWAG Mailing List Confirmation!)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a difference between email clients. There's nothing you can do about it.

Separately, you are using a very old version of PHPMailer (so update it), and you can remove these lines from your script as they're not doing anything:

```
$mail->IsMail(); //This is the default, so does nothing
$mail->ContentType="text/HTML"; //Calling isHTML does this for you, but correctly
$mail->ClearAddresses(); //This does nothing as the instance is destroyed when it goes out of scope
```

Comment: thanks for the info.  I'm a big believer in if it ain't broke don't fix it.

Comment: Depending on exactly which old version you're running, you could be waiting around for someone to exploit the RCE it contains. I'd count that as "broke".